# Angular2 Async Form Validator (return Promise)

Tags: validation, angular, angular2-forms

I'm trying to update the Angular2 Forms Validation example to handle an Async Validation response. This way I can hit an HTTP endpoint to validate a username.

Looking at their code they currently aren't currently using a Promise and it's working just fine:

/** A hero's name can't match the given regular expression */

```
export function forbiddenNameValidator(nameRe: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
    const name = control.value;
    const no = nameRe.test(name);
    return no ? {'forbiddenName': {name}} : null;
  };
}
```

I'm trying to update to return a Promise. Something like:

```
/** A hero's name can't match the given regular expression */
export function forbiddenNameValidator(nameRe: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
    const name = control.value;


    return new Promise( resolve => {
               resolve({'forbiddenName': {name}});
        });

  };
}
```

However, the result I get doesn't display the error message, it's showing undefined.

[image]

My thought is it has something to do with the way they are handling displaying the errors:

```
  onValueChanged(data?: any) {
    if (!this.heroForm) { return; }
    const form = this.heroForm;

    for (const field in this.formErrors) {
      // clear previous error message (if any)
      this.formErrors[field] = '';
      const control = form.get(field);

      if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid) {
        const messages = this.validationMessages[field];
        for (const key in control.errors) {
          this.formErrors[field] += messages[key] + ' ';
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

However I'm not sure of a better way of doing this.

> Angular2 example:
>   https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#!#live-example
>
> Link to my example attempting to return Promise:
>   https://plnkr.co/edit/sDs9pNQ1Bs2knp6tasgI?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you add the AsyncValidator to the SyncValidator Array. AsyncValidators are added in a separate array after the SyncValidators:

```
this.heroForm = this.fb.group({
  'name': [this.hero.name, [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(4),
      Validators.maxLength(24)
    ], 
    [forbiddenNameValidator(/bob/i)] // << separate array
  ],
  'alterEgo': [this.hero.alterEgo],
  'power':    [this.hero.power, Validators.required]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I've put the validator in its own array, not receiving hard errors however not seeing the validation message show. Does everything look alright with the updated PLNKR? https://plnkr.co/edit/sDs9pNQ1Bs2knp6tasgI?p=preview

Comment: `onValueChanged(data?: any)` is the problem here. In this code the method is responsible for building the error output and it's triggered as soon as the value of the form changes, the sync Validators ran by then, the async validators didn't. This is why the method doesn't see the errors result of the async validation. The way how the errors output is build in this example is simply not suitable for async validation. If you print the errors object of the name FormControl to the HTML you'll see the error is there. (`{{heroForm.get('name').errors | json}}`)

Comment: Thanks. How might you recommend changing it? Looking for a "generic" way to handle error printing

Comment: I'm trying to prevent having to have multiple div/error entries in the HTML for each for element

Comment: Simple solution would be to trigger the `onValueChanged(data?: any)` on .statusChanges Observable of the FormControl instead of .valueChanges Observable. Maybe you should also `.filter()` for the `status === "INVALID"`, then it only get's triggered, when there's actually an errors object.

Comment: what am I then filtering status for at that point?                         `this.configForm.statusChanges.subscribe((s) => {

                            console.log("controller STATE changes event fired. received param : " + s);

                            //debugger;
                            //var test = this.configForm.controls.filter(s => s.status === "INVALID"); // not working
                        });`

Comment: the `.filter()` operator has to be used on the statusChanges Observable ;-) `this.configForm.statusChanges.filter((status: string) => status === "INVALID").subscribe((status: string) => {...})`

Comment: right but my question is that's just subscribing to a status change. How do I get access to the actual control?

Comment: `this.configForm.get('name').value`, although in this particular case I'm not sure why you need access to the `.value` of the FormControl, as the `.errors` object contains everything you need to display the error...